# Cant send the result of find query (on an array of obj ids) with ejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to send some data along with my ejs file. The data I need to send is an array of json. I've tried using the code below but i'm confused as to why it's not working when I try to send the result of my query.

I've used the following code

```
 var objIds = [obj_id1, obj_id2....] //assume these are object ids
 Model.find({
            _id : {
                $in: objIds
            }
        }, function(err, doc){
            console.log(doc);  //doc returns an array of json
            var test = [{
                "hi":"bye"
            }];
            res.render('index', arrayOfResults: test});
        });
```

The above code works when I send test but it gives me many errors on the client side when I send doc (the result of the find query). Both test and doc are array of json yet only test works without errors. Does anyone know why?

edit: i should note that the json inside doc would have the following format:

```
{ 
field1: [object]
field2: String
 }
```

Comment: that should work. provide more details. what does mongoose/angular have to do with this? If you know mongoose is returning an array of objects, you can omit that from your testcase.

Comment: @KevinB I was wondering if the fact that field1 was an array of json was the reason that I was getting errors on the client side. If so, what would be the alternative

Comment: if your client is setup to receive it one way, and you're sending it another way, that could of course cause problems. obviously, to fix it, either change how you are sending it or change what the client expects...

Comment: inside my body tag of my ejs file, I have the following:

    ng-init = "arrayOfResults = initArray('<%= arrayOfResults %>')";

Comment: code doesn't work too well in comments.

Comment: yeah, so, fix it so that it has what it needs.

Comment: kevin I'm not sure if you're trolling me or not. Can you help me or no? otherwise stop wasting my time.

Comment: You aren't telling us what you actually need. You simply are specifying that your code doesn't work, which means nothing when we can't see what code doesn't work and the associated errors. You realize errors usually point out specifically what is wrong, right?

Comment: I need to render an ejs file and send data with the form mentioned above. I can send an array of json just fine, but if it's an array of json which has embedded json within it, It seems to cause errors, I'm wondering if that's because you can't send data in the format

Comment: Of course you can send data in that format. but... you appear to be injecting it into an html attribute. What is valid within an html attribute? What happens to an  html attribute wrapped in double quotes when you insert double quotes inside of it? Are you sure you have JSON, and not an object? it's weird to me that you would have a mongodb collection that has raw json stored on a key within a document.

Comment: I'm not using it in that html attribute, rather i'm instantiating it within the angular controller so I can use it later.

Comment: What do you think ng-init is?

Comment: initialize values?

Comment: No, that's what it *does*. it *is* an html attribute.

Comment: well that's what I need it to do. I need it within the controller with the ejs page

Comment: then you'll have to properly escape the data so that it doesn't cause invalid html. but i think this is simply a poor way of injecting this data into your application. Surely getting it separately using $http would be better.

Comment: So what's the alternative to retrieving the data that is sent from the server

Comment: the alternative is to retrieve the data that is sent from the server with angular rather than sending it with the index

Comment: But I need that data when the page is sent.

Comment: Why do you need the data when the page is sent?

Comment: That's not important. What would happen if i did an http request when the controller is initialized, will that have the same effect? ie. 

app.acontroller('controller',function($scope){
    http.get.....
    }

Comment: Yes, it would have the same effect. It would be slightly delayed, but that's normal with angular. It's rather odd to send data with a template.